# Spring Data Mongo Template - Counting an array

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data, aggregation-framework

Mongo document:

```
{
    "_id" : "1",
    "array" : [
        {
            "item" : "item"
        }, 
        {
            "item" : "item"
        }
    ]
}
```

My `mongo shell query` looks like so:

```
db.getCollection('collectionName').aggregate(
    {$match: { _id: "1"}},
    {$project: { count: { $size:"$array" }}}
)
```

Is there anyway to implement this using the `Mongo Template from Spring`?

So far I have this:

```
MatchOperation match = new MatchOperation(Criteria.where("_id").is("1"));
ProjectionOperation project = new ProjectionOperation();
Aggregation aggregate = Aggregation.newAggregation(match, project);
mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregate, collectionName, Integer.class);
```

I think I am only missing the `project` logic but I'm not sure if it is possible to do `$size or equivalent` here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's quite possible, the `$size` operator is supported (see [DATAMONGO-979](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-979) and its implementation **[here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/commit/f5c319f18f9090109790ca2b9a2d7aaa9a2b5153)**). Your implementation could follow this example:

```
import static org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.Aggregation.*;

Aggregation agg = new Aggregation(
    match(where("_id").is("1")), //  
    project() //
        .and("array") //
        .size() //
        .as("count")
);

AggregationResults<IntegerCount> results = mongoTemplate.aggregate(
    agg, collectionName, Integer.class
);
List<IntegerCount> intCount = results.getMappedResults();
```

Comment: That 'where' is now Criteria.where( ... )

Comment: Where does the ```IntegerCount``` came form? Is this only a POJO with attributes _id and count ?

Comment: Note: if you just want the `int` count so you can return it from a method, you can get it out with this `results.getUniqueMappedResult().getInteger("count")`. (You must change `IntegerCount.class` above to `org.bson.Document.class`)

Answer (score 1):

Please find below the sample code. You can change it accordingly for your requirement with collection name, collection name class and array field name.

```
    MatchOperation match = new MatchOperation(Criteria.where("_id").is("1"));
    Aggregation aggregate = Aggregation.newAggregation(match, Aggregation.project().and("array").project("size").as("count"));

    AggregationResults<CollectionNameClass> aggregateResult = mongoOperations.aggregate(aggregate, "collectionName", <CollectionNameClass>.class);

    if (aggregateResult!=null) {
        //You can find the "count" as an attrribute inside "result" key
        System.out.println("Output ====>" + aggregateResult.getRawResults().get("result"));
        System.out.println("Output ====>" + aggregateResult.getRawResults().toMap());
    }
```

**Sample output:-**

```
Output ====>[ { "_id" : "3ea8e671-1e64-4cde-bd78-5980049a772b" , "count" : 47}]
Output ====>{serverUsed=127.0.0.1:27017, waitedMS=0, result=[ { "_id" : "3ea8e671-1e64-4cde-bd78-5980049a772b" , "count" : 47}], ok=1.0}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write query as

```
 Aggregation aggregate = Aggregation.newAggregation(Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("_id").is(1)),
            Aggregation.project().and("array").size().as("count")); mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregate, collectionName, Integer.class);
```

It will execute the following query `{ "aggregate" : "collectionName" , "pipeline" : [ { "$match" : { "_id" : 1}} , { "$project" : { "count" : { "$size" : [ "$array"]}}}]}`